# Mark GitHub Action as optional

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm adding a GitHub Action to a repo, but it doesn't directly affect my CI/CD build. Is it possible to mark it as optional, so that if it fails, it's not actually blocking my workflow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`continue-on-error`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepscontinue-on-error) step property.

Script step example:

```
      - name: Test continue-on-error
        continue-on-error: true
        run: exit 1
```

Action step example:

```
      - name: My action
        continue-on-error: true
        uses: owner/action-that-sometimes-fails@v1
```

Comment: What if you don't want CI to wait for it to finish?

Comment: Like @LukePighetti, I'd like to unblock PR merges while some long-running leg completes asynchronously after merge. Does anyone know how to achieve that?